# Titanium Studio on Mac Android device not found

Tags: titanium

I'm on OS 10.9, Titanium 3.1.3.201309132423, Latest and greatest SDK - Nexus 4 on 4.3 with UBS Debugging checked, Unknown sources allowed. If I plug in the device Titanium does not see the device, however under Eclips I can install/debug on the device just fine. I have Googled to my hearts end with no luck... Sooo, any ideas what I could be doing wrong in Titanium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium Studio needs to be properly configured to use Android SDK. Check if you have correct paths set in preferences. You can find more details in [Appcelerator documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK-section-29004851_InstallingtheAndroidSDK-ConfiguringStudio).

Comment: Would that make adb get out of date? After each attempted with Titanium if I check adb for devices it tells me its out of date and reboots itself.

Comment: ** I should note that I have had Ti installed for well over a year, used it plenty, but just came back to using it after a couple months off.

Comment: Titanium needs Android SDK in version 2.3.3 to operate properly + it's good to install latest one. Maybe you changed path to adb when you stopped using Titanium and now studio don't know how to find it.

Also you can try compiling your project using console:
`titanium build -p android -T device`